# Ruby Mongo Driver 2.0.0 connection status

Tags: ruby, mongodb

Read the docs, searched the stack, but I can't find a very simple 
function: How do I check if the connection has been established or not?

establishing DB connection with

`db = Mongo::Client.new([ '127.0.0.1:27017' ], :database => 'test')`

From time to time I forget to launch the mongodb database and then the driver tries to connect and well... does not say's a lot about the connection itself.

Is there some kind of .isConnected? method or anything to find
the connection status of current `Mongo::Client` instance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Version 1.x of the Mongo ruby driver did expose a `connected?` method on `Mongo::Connection`, but it's been moved in v2 to [live on `Mongo::Server`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/Mongo/Server/Connectable#connected%3F-instance_method), however its meaning has changed somewhat.

Here's an example of using this method:

```
mongo = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://localhost/mycollection')
#=> #<Mongo::Client:0x70279909414900 cluster=localhost:27017> 
mongo.cluster.servers.first.connected?
#=> true
```

In v2 of the Mongo ruby driver, it will raise an exception when trying to use an invalid connection, for example, `Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable`, based on the connection parameters about timeouts. For your purposes of simply checking whether the connection has been established, maybe something like:

```
mongo = Mongo::Client.new('mongodb://localhost/mycollection')
mongo.list_databases => # raise error or return an array
```

Comment: Upvoted - this is a great answer except for hosted systems (like ObjectRocket) where list_databases will throw an exception because you don't have permission to see other peoples' databases.